# If variables in Elixir are immutable why can you append to tuples and lists?

Tags: elixir

In the example below, I have created a list then I have added a new value into that list. How is this possible if Elixir is all about immutability?

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
  iex> [1,2,3,4]
l = l ++ [5]
  iex> [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If I am not mistaken this is reassigning the list to the same list, this should be impossible and when I call l again it should print out 1 through 4 not 1 through 5. What do I not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with mutability vs. immutability is more of an issue with physical memory.  If I were to define a list `l` and it's located starting at memory location 1000, and then multiple threads/process etc. all try to append to the list at once I run into issues of deciding whose writes are actually processed and in what order.  On the other hand if every time someone tries to modify `l` I copy the contents of the list at 1000 to a new memory address then there's no need to worry about locks or mutexes or any sort of mechanism like that because each thread/process etc is getting its own copy.

*NB this is a gross oversimplification of what's actually happening under the hood but for this discussion it is essentially what's happening.*

The actual name is not as important as the fact that each time I modify the list I copy it to a new memory location.

Hence if I had

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and it started out at memory 1000

and I run

```
l = l ++ [5]
```

then the `l` at 1000 is discarded and a new `l` is created at some different memory location.  Even though the name is the same, it is two different memory locations under the hood. As long as they don't share memory locations, concurrency is significantly easier since I don't have to deal with locks or mutexes or other mechanisms to deal with multiple writes to the same physical memory address happening at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

When you assign a new value to a variable, you actually **create a new variable with the same name**.

First of all, when you do `l ++ [5]`, nothing is append to`l`, because it is immutable. Instead, a **new list** containing `l` and the new element is created.

Now when you do `l = l ++ [5]`, you don’t really append to the variable `l` either, you just drop the former `l` variable and create a new one to store the new list created by concatening `[5]` to your former `l` variable.

Comment: Thank you for that, very clear explanation. So does this then break the whole immutability for concurrency, inwhich Elixir is fantastic at? This would surely repoen race conditions and all the issues that come with mutability.

Comment: I think @ErrolHassall you are misunderstanding things. The issue with concurrency is multiple execution contexts (I E threads, processes etc.) accessing the same physical memory location. When Elixir rebinds a value the rebound value is placed in a different memory location.

Comment: Yes I have forgotten that part, thanks for adding that. I have only done very basic concurrency work